# What does a question mark mean when listing all services?

Tags: linux, debian, service

After executing the command `service --status-all` I get a listing of all the services on my machine. I get an output like this.

```
[ ? ]  acpi-fakekey
[ ? ]  acpi-support
[ + ]  acpid
[ - ]  anacron
[ + ]  apache2
[ + ]  atd
[ - ]  bootlogd
```

What does a `?` mean? I have always assumed a `+` means the process is started and a `-` means the process is stoppped. What state is a service preceded by `?` in?

Here's the contents of my `/proc/version` file incase it helps anyone to answer me.

```
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-45)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question mark in the output of `service --status-all` is printed when the `/usr/sbin/service` script does not find status line in the case structure in the related script under `/etc/init.d`.

If you look at the `/usr/sbin/service` script, you can find an if statement like this:

```
if ! grep -qs "\Wstatus)" "$SERVICE"; then
    #printf " %s %-60s %s\n" "[?]" "$SERVICE:" "unknown" 1>&2
    echo " [ ? ]  $SERVICE" 1>&2
    continue
else
```

Comment: ... and since that regular expression is not correct, it will also falsely print a `?` if the `status)` line does not have a non-"[:alnum:]" character in front of it.